# how to read from pandas dataframe with networkx versions before 2.0

Tags: python, networkx

I need to generate a networkx graph with arc attributes from a pandas dataframe. In networkx version 2.0, I am aware of the from_pandas_dataframe function and I did what I wanted as follows:

```
graph=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df_t, 'node2', 'node1', ['Transit Time','arctype','node1type','node2type','cpt'],nx.DiGraph())
```

However  at the moment I have to use networkx 1.9., which does not have from_pandas_dataframe function. I was wondering how I can do that. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. I am deploying my application in a framework which has only networkx v1.9. I don't have time to upgrade the networkx version in the framework so I am trying to change my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [IPython](https://ipython.org/), you can find the file which defines `nx.from_pandas_dataframe`:

```
In [125]: import networkx as nx
In [126]: nx.from_pandas_dataframe?
...
File:      ~/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/networkx/convert_matrix.py
```

Inspecting this file (or the [source on github](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L130)) shows `from_pandas_dataframe` is fairly simple and depends only on one helper function, [`_prep_create_using`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/convert.py#L34).

So you could create a file `utils_networkx.py` and insert there the definitions of 
`_prep_create_using` and `from_pandas_dataframe`. Just be sure to place `utils_networkx.py` in a directory listed in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable so that Python can import it as a module.

Then you could use it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import utils_networkx as UNX

r = np.random.RandomState(seed=5)
ints = r.randint(1, 10, size=(3,2))
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = ['D', 'A', 'E']
df = pd.DataFrame(ints, columns=['weight', 'cost'])
df[0] = a
df['b'] = b
print(df)
#    weight  cost  0  b
# 0       4     7  A  D
# 1       7     1  B  A
# 2      10     9  C  E
G = UNX.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 0, 'b', ['weight', 'cost'])
print(G['E']['C']['weight'])
# 10
print(G['E']['C']['cost'])
# 9
```

The code above comes from the [`from_pandas_dataframe` docstring](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/convert_matrix.py#L173).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Following your lead, I copied the source code for from_pandas_dataframe to my script along with _prep_create_using. The source is provided in http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/networkx/convert_matrix.html#from_pandas_dataframe.

Thanks again.